# Javascript and this?

Tags: javascript, this

Something is troubling me with the 'this' Object in Javascript.

So 'this' can be defined has a property belonging to the execution context.

And when we call a function from a specific context, 'this' will be defined by the callee.

Now let's suppose I got this code:

```js
function f4(){
    this.herp = "derp";
    this.test = '2';
}

function Thing(){
    this.prop1="nothingSpecial";
    this.test = '1';
    f4();
    f4.call(this);
}

 var thing = new Thing();
 console.log('herp:'+thing.herp);
 console.log('test:'+thing.test);
```

In the code below, If i hadn't add f4.call(this), thing.herp would be undefined. According to me, f4() and f4.call(this) is the same in the context of the Thing function but it's not the case.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @hindmost Why when we call f4() the first time it doesn't override the this of the context Thing as the second statement (f4.call(this))?

Comment: Sorry, but you need to read the object section on the You don't know js, it will really help. JavaScrfipt this is kind of confusing always

Comment: You have wrong grasp on it. `this` is totally unrelated to execution context unless you assign it manually. Just read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. if the function is called with the new keyword this will point to the newly constructed objects**

```
function fun() { this.a = 3; }

var obj = new fun();

console.log(obj.a); // 3
```

**2. if we use hard binding (bind function) this will point to object that we pass in bind function argument**

```
function fun1() { this.a = 3; }

var obj1 = { a: 0 };

var fun2 = fun1.bind(obj1);

fun2();

console.log(obj1.a); // 3
```

now, when we call fun2 **this** keyword will point to obj1, even when we assign fun2 to another object and call from it using a dot notation

```
var obj2 = { a: 0, fun: fun2 };

obj2.fun();

console.log(obj2.a) // 0
```

but when we use fun2 as a constructor with the new keyword, in that case **this** will point to the newly created object, we can say that new keyword is stronger than hard binding

```
function fun1() { this.a = 3; }

var obj1 = { a: 0 };

var fun2 = fun1.bind(obj1)

var obj2 = new fun2()

console.log(obj1.a) // 0
console.log(obj2.a) // 3
```

**3. If we call function using a call or apply function this will point to object which we passed in function arguments.**

```
function fun() { this.a = 3; }

var obj = {a: 0};

fun.call(obj);

console.log(obj.a); // 3
```

**4. If we call function directly from object using a dot notation this will point to that object**

```
function fun() { this.a = 3; }

var obj = {a: 0, fun: fun};

obj.fun();

console.log(obj.a); // 3
```

**5. In almost every other cases this will point to global object**

**Now let's go to your example**

```
function f4(){

    this.herp = "derp";

    this.test = '2';

}



function Thing(){

    this.prop1="nothingSpecial";

    this.test = '1';

    f4();

    f4.call(this);

}



 var thing = new Thing();

 console.log('herp:'+thing.herp);

 console.log('test:'+thing.test);
```

When you use Thing() as a constructor with new keyword, **this** inside a Thing function point to newly created object (lets assume for simplicity that point to thing, but in real new operator creates a new object, then use a constructor function to set it up and at end assign this object to thing)

As a **this** point to thing object you created a two variables inside of thing - prop1 and test:

```
thing = {

    prop1: "nothingSpecial",

    test: "1"

}
```

then when you call f4 for the the first time **this** inside of it points to global, it is no matter that f4 is called insiade of Thing function. So you set 2 global variables herp and test. At this point there is no thing.herp variable so when you tried to log it out, console prints undefined.

```
thing = {

    prop1: "nothingSpecial",

    test: "1"

}

// global objects

console.log(test) // 2

console.log(herp) // "derp"
```

Next, you called f4 using a call function, so you passed **this** from Thing to f4, as **this** in Thing point to thing object, **this** in f4 also point to thing object, so now f4 function created new variable herp inside of thing and overwrite test from '1' to '2'

```
thing = {

    prop1: "nothingSpecial",

    test: "2",

    herp: "derp"


}
```